# incompatible types: required int found object error in generic linkedlist

Tags: java, arrays, generics, linked-list

I am writing a radix sort algorithm (that ONLY sorts integer) and have run into a problem, which could possibly be an easy fix, I just can't seem to find it.

I create and array of linked lists here to hold my integers:

```
LinkedList[] buckets = {new LinkedList<Integer>(), new LinkedList<Integer>(), new LinkedList<Integer>(), new LinkedList<Integer>(), new LinkedList<Integer>(), new LinkedList<Integer>(), new LinkedList<Integer>(), new LinkedList<Integer>(), new LinkedList<Integer>(), new LinkedList<Integer>()};
```

That is the generic linkedlist from the util and I only need it to hold integers.
My problem is when I try to run this code

```
            for (int j = 0; j < buckets.length; j++) {
            while (!buckets[j].isEmpty()) {
                a[pos] = buckets[j].removeFirst();
                pos++;
            }
```

On the line where I remove from my "queue" I get the required int found object error.
My linkedlists are hold Integers anyway so why does it say that it is an object? Do I have to downcast somewhere or something along those lines?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Look at your declaration:

```
LinkedList[] buckets
```

You've declared an array of *raw* `LinkedList` references. You would need to tell the compiler that they'll be `LinkedList<Integer>` values:

```
LinkedList<Integer> buckets = ...;
```

Unfortunately, arrays and generics don't play terribly nicely together. I suggest you use a `List<LinkedList<Integer>>`, like this:

```
List<LinkedList<Integer>> buckets = new ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    buckets.add(new LinkedList<Integer>());
}
```

Then:

```
for (LinkedList<Integer> bucket : buckets)
{
    while (!bucket.isEmpty())
    {
        a[pos] = bucket.removeFirst();
        pos++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see how this would work, but it would really screw up the rest of my code because it relies on the numbered positions of an array. Is there any way for arrays an generics to work together? If not I think I am just going to write my own non-generic linkedlist structure.

Comment: @Cheesegraterr: Why would that screw anything up? The numbered positions within the list should still be absolutely fine. An `ArrayList` preserves insertion order.